# Import errors from 3rd party dependencies (`react-hook-form`) in Vite library

Tags: node.js, next.js, vite, es6-modules, react-hook-form

I'm currently writing a reusable UI library with Vite which is a simple wrapper around ShadCN Uis components. ATM I'm only using the library in a couple of NextJSs apps and everything is working as expected when only using the library in pages router components but I'm getting import errors when using it in app router components.

The errors are caused by imports (& re-exports) from third party dependency `react-hook-form` in the library.
In detail I'm getting the following when running `npm run build`:

```
./node_modules/shadcn-ui-lib/dist/index6.js Attempted import error: 'FormProvider' is not exported from 'react-hook-form' (imported as 'u').

Import trace for requested module: ./node_modules/shadcn-ui-lib/dist/index6.js ./node_modules/shadcn-ui-lib/dist/index.js ./src/app/rsc/page.tsx

./node_modules/shadcn-ui-lib/dist/index6.js Attempted import error: 'Controller' is not exported from 'react-hook-form' (imported as 'p')
```

Here's some excerpt from `index6.js` within `node_modules` of the consuming app which is mentioned in the error:

```js
import { Label as f } from "./index5.js";
import { Slot as F } from "@radix-ui/react-slot";
import * as e from "react";
import { FormProvider as u, Controller as p, useFormContext as x } from "react-hook-form";
import { useForm as M } from "react-hook-form";
const R = u;

// ...

export { R as Form, C as FormControl, w as FormDescription, $ as FormField, I as FormItem, g as FormLabel, E as FormMessage, M as useForm, a as useFormField };
```

There are a few interesting things for which I don't really have an explanation:

- The error only occurs when using the library in app router components. When using it in pages router components everything works as expected.
- The import of `Slot` from `@radix-ui/react-slot` is working as expected even though I'm treating the dependencies to `@radix-ui/react-slot` and `react-hook-form` the same way (see `package.json` later).
- When looking at the `node_modules` folder in my consuming app I can see that `react-hook-form` is installed and the `FormProvider` is exported from `react-hook-form` as expected.
- The errors occur even when I'm not importing anything from `react-hook-form` directly in my consuming app but as soon as I'm using **any** component from the library.

## Implementation details

**library/vite.config.ts**

```
// @ts-ignore Not sure how to solve this but not worth the time to figure it out...
import * as packageJson from './package.json';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react({
      // Not really required but seems to make the bundle a bit smaller
      jsxRuntime: 'classic',
    }),
    dts({
      include: ['src/**/*'],
    }),
  ],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.ts'),
      formats: ['es'],
      fileName: 'index',
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      // Do not include the deps and peerDeps in the build.
      external: [...Object.keys(packageJson.peerDependencies || {}), ...Object.keys(packageJson.dependencies)],
      // `preserveModules` makes the lib tree shakable (in combination with `sideEffects: false` in `package.json`).
      output: { preserveModules: true, exports: 'named' },
    },

    target: 'esnext',
    sourcemap: true,
  },
});
```

**library/package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "shadcn-ui-lib",
  // ...
  "sideEffects": false,
  "type": "module",
  "exports": {
    ".": "./dist/index.js",
    "./styles.css": "./dist/styles.css",
    "./tailwind-config": "./dist/tailwind.config.ts"
  },
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc && vite build && npm run build:styles && npm run copy:files-to-dist",
    "build:styles": "postcss ./src/index.css -o ./dist/styles.css && node ./build-scripts/inject-tw-directives",
    "copy:files-to-dist": "copyfiles -f ./tailwind.config.ts dist",
    "dev": "vite",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    // ...
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    // ...
    "react-hook-form": "^7.50.1",
    // ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    // ...
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.0.8",
    "vite-plugin-dts": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "lucide-react": "^0.323.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.34",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  }
}
```

**library/src/components/form.tsx**
The Source which holds the troublesome imports & re-expors from `react-hook-form`):

```
'use client';

import { cn } from '../lib/css.utils.js';
import { Label } from './label.js';
import type * as LabelPrimitive from '@radix-ui/react-label';
import { Slot } from '@radix-ui/react-slot';
import * as React from 'react';
import { Controller, type ControllerProps, type FieldError, type FieldPath, type FieldValues, FormProvider, useForm, useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form';

const Form = FormProvider;

// Definitions of form components, hooks etc. (`FormItem`, `FormField`, `useFormField`, ...)

export { useFormField, Form, FormItem, FormLabel, FormControl, FormDescription, FormMessage, FormField, useForm };
```

**consuming-app/src/app/rsc/page.tsx**

```
import { Card } from 'shadcn-ui-lib';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main>
      <Card>RSC test page</Card>
    </main>
  );
}
```

## Some wild guesses I have

I explicitly set my library to "ESM only" as trying to export both CJS & ESM was causing issues in the consuming apps which I wasn't able to solve otherwise. Maybe this is causing the issue?
When comparing `@radix-ui/react-slot/package.json` (which is working fine) & `react-hook-form/package.json` (which causes issues) I saw that `react-slot` doesn't provide any `cjs` files whilst `react-hook-form` does provide `cjs` & `esm` files.

Are my consuming apps (or the library itself) maybe trying to import the `cjs` files from `react-hook-form` instead of the `esm` files? If so, how can I fix this?

## Reproduction

You can download both, a minimal example of the library and a test consuming app here:

- https://github.com/CombeeMike/shadcn-ui-lib (the library)
- https://github.com/CombeeMike/shadcn-ui-lib-test (the consuming app)

The issues can reproduced by running `npm i && npm run dev` or `npm run build` in the consuming app.

## Conclusion

I'm rather new to library authoring and am still having trouble understanding the ins- & outs of ESM & CJS and all implications of choosing one and/or the other.

Also, I'm not sure if the issue is caused by my library, the consuming apps or the third party dependencies.

Anyhow, I'd really appreciate some help with this and would be happy to provide more information if needed.

## Update

I did some fiddling around directly with `react-hook-form/package.json` in my consuming app and found the following:

When removing the `react-server` condition from the [conditional exports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#conditional-exports), everything is working as expected (at least on first glance as I get no more build errors...):

```js
"exports": {
  "./package.json": "./package.json",
  ".": {
    "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
    "react-server": "./dist/react-server.esm.mjs", // <-- Remove this
    "import": "./dist/index.esm.mjs",
    "require": "./dist/index.cjs.js"
  }
},
```

So it seems that the errors are not caused by ESM/CJS but somehow by this `react-server` export.

### Question

This obviously raises the question of what I can change in my consuming app or library to make this work?

FYI, this is not an issue when directly importing `react-hook-form` in an Next JS app router app but only when imported "through" my library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-declare `useForm` which is imported from `react-hook-form` before re-exporting it from the libs `form.tsx`:

```
'use client';

// ...

import {
  // ...
  useForm as useFormImport,
} from 'react-hook-form';

// ...

const useForm = useFormImport;

export { useForm, /* ... */ };
```

## Why does this help?

The original export of `useForm` from `react-hook-form` does not have a `use client` directive and I guess that the server component which imports from my lib does not consider the `use client` directive from `form.tsx` when simple passing `useForm` through like I initially did (i.e. when re-exporting `useFormImport` directly).

However, it seems like re-declaring it before export, somehow "attaches" the `use client` directive to the re-declared `useForm`.

## Why was this an issue when not importing anything from `form.tsx` in my server component?

Because my lib is exporting all its components from 1 barrel file (`index.ts`). So even when only importing `Card` from `index.ts` in a server component, React seems to be processing **all** exports from that barrel file.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78075430/1273551) from @morganney provides more details on this & actually lead me to this conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

The answer already given from Alexander is essentially correct, however not well explained.

Your consuming app is importing the `Card` like [this](https://github.com/CombeeMike/shadcn-ui-lib-test/blob/main/src/app/rsc/page.tsx#L1C1-L1C38):

```js
import { Card } from 'shadcn-ui-lib';
```

So according to your libraries defined [`exports`](https://github.com/CombeeMike/shadcn-ui-lib/blob/main/package.json#L8-L12) this will import from the barrel file defined at [src/index.ts](https://github.com/CombeeMike/shadcn-ui-lib/blob/main/src/index.ts), and thus attempt to also load the exports from `./components/form.js` which includes `react-hook-form`.

[Next.js 14 defaults to React Server Components](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components#using-server-components-in-nextjs) and you have to explicitly opt-in to [Client Components](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components). Client components need to be used when your page has functionality that depends on Browser API's, like event handlers, and `react-hook-form` definitely depends on Browser APIs, so when defining a Next.js page that depends on `react-hook-form` you must define `'use client'` at the top of your file.

**Simply add this to `src/app/rsc/page.tsx` inside of the consuming app**:

```js
'use client';
```

You added this directive in the wrong location.

Notes:

- Barrel files are a bit of an anti-pattern since they make your imports less clear, and may create problems for tree shaking resulting in larger bundles. You should consider redefining `exports` inside of your library to allow importing individual components.
- There is an [RFC for defining React Server Component exports](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/main/text/0227-server-module-conventions.md#react-server-conditional-exports) that makes use of a `react-server` conditional to define a module's export when consumed on the server. React Hook Form is making use of this in their [package.json](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/master/package.json#L22) file, so that is why the error messages are able to suggest the possible exports for the server:

  ```
   ○ Compiling /rsc ...
   ⨯ ./node_modules/shadcn-ui-lib/dist/index.js
  export 'useForm' (reexported as 'useForm') was not found in 'react-hook-form'  (possible exports: appendErrors, get, set)
  ```

Comment: I still don't fully understand why the `use client` within the "most specific" location `form.tsx` isn't enough but your suggestion works, so that's good! Also I wasn't aware of the fact that barrel files in libs are an anti pattern so I'll see how to work around it.

Comment: The build for your library is distinct from the build for your consuming app, so the `use client` directive in your library has no effect for creating a client/server boundary when building your consuming app. The directive isn't even present any longer in your built library files. Check out the [caveats](https://react.dev/reference/react/use-client#caveats) for `use client` in the docs. Whether barrel files are an anti-pattern is up to you and your projects goals, but for me they often become more trouble than they are worth.

Comment: FYI, I just realized that your proposed solution (`use client` in my `page.tsx`) did not actually work. I added `use client` to my libs `index.ts` file which seemed to work at first but lead to other issues (too much to explain here). What really worked is [re-declaring the useForm before re-exporting it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78082859/1273551).

Comment: One more thing I forgot to mention initially: I'm using [rollup-plugin-preserve-directives](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-preserve-directives) in my vite config which is why `use client` directives are actually still present in my built lib files.

Comment: My answer was based off of your linked repos. I can push a commit to the repo indicating that my changes fixed your build error. Whatever you are doing now in another code base is a black box to me, but seems hackish.

Comment: Interesting, I just tried in the test-repo as well & your suggestion is working there. Not sure what the difference between the test repo and my real life project is but I don't want to invest anymore time on this tbh. My outlined solution seems to be working in my real life project and since the lib is only meant for personal use, I can live with a "hackish" solution. Thanks for your help, really appreciated!